# Why are files lwith the same time stamp not sorted alphabetically when listed using "ls -lt"?

Tags: macos, unix, ls

I read that `ls -lt` will order files by modification time before sorting by lexicographical order.

However, when I use the command with this syntax, I get this result:

```
ls -lt
total 192
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  6988 Aug 20 21:17 sorting_files.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  4416 Aug 20 20:56 sorting_dirs.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  6552 Aug 20 15:12 lists.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  7692 Aug 20 15:12 printing.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  7868 Aug 20 01:05 assets.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  5344 Aug 20 01:05 freeing.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  4860 Aug 20 01:05 reversing.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  8028 Aug 20 01:04 listing.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  2620 Aug 19 23:24 errors.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  3096 Aug 19 23:24 main.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  5564 Aug 19 21:07 chmod.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  7140 Aug 19 21:07 sorting.o
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  4760 Aug 19 21:07 parsing.o
```

`parsing.o` is coming after `sorting.o`. Why?

Using `ls -lT` shows that these two (plus `chmod.o`) have the same timestamp:

```
ls -lT
total 192
[...]
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  5564 Aug 19 21:07:50 2018 chmod.o
[...]
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  4760 Aug 19 21:07:50 2018 parsing.o
[...]
-rw-r--r--  1 elfryskai  staff  7140 Aug 19 21:07:50 2018 sorting.o
[...]
```

EDIT: I'm running MacOS with a APFS volume.

Comment: What file system are you using here? (I assume macOS due to user group name, but is it HFS+ or APFS?)

Comment: @slhck I have a APFS volume

Comment: Maybe the resolution of these timestamps is better than one second. What does `stat parsing.o sorting.o` say?

Comment: 16777220 3117665 -rw-r--r-- 1 elfryskai staff 0 4760 "Aug 20 21:17:54 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" 4194304 16 0 parsing.o
    
16777220 3117667 -rw-r--r-- 1 elfryskai staff 0 7140 "Aug 19 23:44:10 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" "Aug 19 21:07:50 2018" 4194304 16 0 sorting.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's latest file system, APFS, stores timestamps in nanosecond rather than seconds ([as HFS+ used to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Criticisms)).

This may explain a different sorting of the files, even though they appear to have been modified at the same time.

To test that, excuse my sloppy C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    struct stat attr;
    stat("/path/to/file", &attr);
    printf("Last modified time: %ld", (long)&attr.st_mtime);
}
```

Then:

```
gcc -o test.o test.c && test.o
```

Would print:

```
Last modified time: 140734785103288
```

Comment: Added a hacky example to get the timestamps, which you may want to verify in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, your code didn't work for me unfortunatly, but by seeking things that way, I found st_mtime have a struct with nanoseconds in it -> attr.st_mtimespec.tv_nsec.